# String to yyyyMMdd in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following **possible pattern string** and i want to **convert to** **yyyyMMdd**(20160602) in **vba**.
        and i already tried Format("20160602", "00000000"). but it gives 00201662

```
'possible pattern
20160602
201662
2016062
2016602
```

At the same time i don't want following kinds of long code

```
Dim trgetYmdFrom As String

trgetYmdFrom = "2016602"
If Len(trgetYmdFrom) = 6 Then
    trgetYmdFrom  = Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 1, 4) & "0" & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 1) & "0" & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 6, 1)
ElseIf Len(trgetYmdFrom) = 7 Then
    If Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 1) >= 0 And Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 1) <= 1 Then
        trgetYmdFrom  = Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 1, 4) & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 2) & "0" & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 7, 1)
    Else
        trgetYmdFrom  = Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 1, 4) & "0" & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 1) & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 6, 2)
    End If
ElseIf Len(trgetYmdFrom) = 8 Then
    trgetYmdFrom  = trgetYmdFrom
End If
```

I need **shortest way** to convert **string to yyyyMMdd**

Note:

> In my case 2016111 should be consider as 20161101

Comment: Are we working with dates?

Comment: @RomcelGeluz input is string type value

Comment: You might have some problems with your patterns: is "2016101" the first of January, or the tenth of October?

Comment: You have an example of 201662 which is unambiguous, but what would you expect if you had 2016111 in the data? Is that November 1 or January 11?

Comment: @Vincent G October

Comment: @Lord Peter take as November 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time on this problem.I can't able to get any simplified method to convert string to yyyyMMdd.
So i make formula as same as previous long code for convert string to yyyyMMdd.At the last the code will be like following.

**Code:**

```
Dim trgetYmdFrom As String

Sub can_Click()

    stringToYYYYMMDD ("20160602")
    stringToYYYYMMDD ("201662")
    stringToYYYYMMDD ("2016062")
    stringToYYYYMMDD ("2016602")
    stringToYYYYMMDD ("2016111")
    stringToYYYYMMDD ("2016122")
End Sub

Sub stringToYYYYMMDD(s As String)

    Range("A1").Value = s
    Range("A2").Formula = "=IF(INT(LEN(A1))=6,LEFT(A1,4)&0&MID(A1,5,1)&0&MID(A1,6,1),IF(INT(LEN(A1))=7,LEFT(A1,4)&IF(INT(MID(A1,5,1))<=1,MID(A1,5,2)&0&MID(A1,7,1),0&MID(A1,5,1)&MID(A1,6,2)),A1))"
    trgetYmdFrom = Range("A2").Value
    Range("A1:A2").Clear

    'debug log
    Debug.Print trgetYmdFrom
End Sub
```

**Debug log:**

```
20160602
20160602
20160602
20160602
20161101
20161202
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
trgetYmdFrom = Format(trgetYmdFrom, "yyyyMMdd")
```

**EDIT 1**

This is what I mean. You can try all of your options.

```
Dim trgetYmdFrom As String

trgetYmdFrom = "20160602"

If Len(trgetYmdFrom) = 6 Then
trgetYmdFrom = Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 1) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 6, 1)
    ElseIf Len(trgetYmdFrom) = 7 And Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 1) = 0 Then
    trgetYmdFrom = Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 2) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 6, 1)
    ElseIf Len(trgetYmdFrom) = 7 And Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 6, 1) = 0 Then
    trgetYmdFrom = Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 1) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 6, 2)
    ElseIf Len(trgetYmdFrom) = 8 Then
    trgetYmdFrom = Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 5, 2) & "." & Mid(trgetYmdFrom, 7, 2)
End If

trgetYmdFrom = Format(trgetYmdFrom, "yyyymmdd")
MsgBox trgetYmdFrom
```

**"Simplified Version"**

```
Dim s As String
s = "20160602"

If Len(s) = 6 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 1) & "." & Mid(s, 6, 1)
        ElseIf Len(s) = 7 And Mid(s, 5, 1) = 0 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 2) & "." & Mid(s, 6, 1)
        ElseIf Len(s) = 7 And Mid(s, 6, 1) = 0 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 1) & "." & Mid(s, 6, 2)
        ElseIf Len(s) = 8 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 2) & "." & Mid(s, 7, 2)
End If

s = Format(s, "yyyymmdd")
```

**EDIT 3**

```
Dim s As String
s = "2016111"

If Len(s) = 6 And Mid(s, 5, 1) >= 0 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 1) & "." & Mid(s, 6, 1)
        ElseIf Len(s) = 7 And Mid(s, 5, 1) <= 1 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 2) & "." & Mid(s, 7, 1)
        ElseIf Len(s) = 7 And Mid(s, 5, 1) > 1 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 1) & "." & Mid(s, 7, 1)
        ElseIf Len(s) = 7 And Mid(s, 6, 1) > 0 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 1) & "." & Mid(s, 6, 2)
        ElseIf Len(s) = 8 Then
    s = Mid(s, 1, 4) & "." & Mid(s, 5, 2) & "." & Mid(s, 7, 2)
End If

s = Format(s, "yyyymmdd")
```

Comment: Try to get your input,with dot (.) `trgetYmdFrom = Format("2016.6.02", "yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: input string not contain any .

Comment: You can create it in vba

Comment: In my case I don't want to add any.,-,/ into input.I need more simplified code

Comment: What is the problem? Your input is without .,/ just temporary is added. The output is what you need...and what is the problem if the code is like that? It can't be more simplified.

Comment: Thank you for answer.But i think when input like 2016111,201621 then you code would not work.

Comment: Try now with **EDIT 3**

Answer (score 0):

Using user's Function is suitable.

```
Sub test()
    Dim trgetYmdFrom As String
    trgetYmdFrom = "2016602"
    trgetYmdFrom = ChangeFormat(trgetYmdFrom)
    Debug.Print trgetYmdFrom
End Sub


Function ChangeFormat(myDay As String)
    Dim y As String, m As String, d As String
    Select Case Len(myDay)
    Case 8
        y = Left(myDay, 4)
        m = Mid(myDay, 5, 2)
        d = Right(myDay, 2)
    Case 6
        y = Left(myDay, 4)
        m = Mid(myDay, 5, 1)
        d = Right(myDay, 1)
    Case 7
        If Mid(myDay, 5, 1) = "0" Then
            y = Left(myDay, 4)
            m = Mid(myDay, 5, 2)
            d = Right(myDay, 1)
        Else
            y = Left(myDay, 4)
            m = Mid(myDay, 5, 1)
            d = Right(myDay, 2)
        End If
    End Select
    ChangeFormat = Format(DateSerial(y, m, d), "yyyymmdd")

End Function
```